# URL reroute on a submit button I think is happening too quickly

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a submit button on a page that sends data to a server database through an ajax call. The submit button has an onclick property which looks like this:

```
onClick="if(confirm('Leave Page?')){parent.location='home.php';}"
```

If the user clicks OK on the confirm message, it reroutes them to home.php, but none of the data which was supposed to be submitted actually goes into the database. However, if the user clicks Cancel on the confirm message, it stays on the page and the data is successfully submitted to the database.

Any way to get around this? I'm guessing the onclick property activates before the ajax call, and if they select OK then the URL reroute takes precedence over the ajax call to send data to the DB. Any alternative ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering the Leave Page dialog too early. It should be activated only after success is reported by your ajax call